# Putting check box data in an array then checking it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am passing some data...

```
<input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="School" />
<input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Home" />
```

I know the data is arriving okay, because I am checking

```
echo implode(",",$_POST['type']);
```

Now, I wish to also check if a certain tickbox was ticked(each one in turn).

I am trying something like...

```
if(!empty($_POST['type'])) {
 if(in_array("School",$type)) {
  // Code here
 }
}
```

But I end up seeing `Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument`.  Is this not an array I am passing?  Is there another function I can use to do this?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['type'])` so you can see what's in it

Comment: Have you set `$type`? - I can't see an assignment in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$type` is not declared. Try:

```
if(!empty($_POST['type'])) {
    if(in_array("School", $_POST['type'])) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my...I set $type.  It's the array imploded.  I didn't spot that I was referring to it there.  THANK YOU!